# A sequence with two distinct limits

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

I just wanted to check I was right about this:

Consider $X=\{1,2,3\}$ equipped with the topology $T=\{\emptyset,\{1,2\},X\}.$

Then the sequence $(1,2,1,2,1,2,\ldots)$ converges to both $1$ and $2$ in $X$.

Is this right?

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.